# An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Minus')

Tags: angular

[image]

need to run the project but it show the

> error: An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read properties of
> undefined (reading 'Minus') See
> "C:\Users\DEVELO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-t4Itqs\angular-errors.log"
> for further details.

Comment: somewhere in your code something is undefined. like "yourVariable.Minus". search Minus in your code and find it. share your code so we can help better. you can put ? for null check: "yourVariable?.Minus"